# Shuffle NSString characters and arrange in blocks

Tags: iphone, nsstring, shuffle

I am trying to develop a puzzle game where we display a shuffled word in blocks and user has to tap in proper order to form the word.I have an array of around 3k words and I have shuffled the array and formed a jumbled array.Now I want to pick a word eventually string,shuffle it and display the shuffled arrangement in boxes,say for instance the word is cricket,it should appear something of the below format on the screen:

[image]

Here is how I shuffled the array and formed a jumbled one

```
srandom(time(NULL));
for (NSInteger x=0;x<[greWordsArray count];x++)
{
   NSInteger randomNumber = (random() % ([greWordsArray count] - x)) + x;
   [greWordsArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:x withObjectAtIndex:randomNumber];
}
```

I also forgot to say I have a "new" button where if user clicks it,new word should appear and as usual it should be in shuffled mode,then display in blocks.

Can some one please guide me on how to accomplish this,I wonder what to use for displaying characters in blocks,whether it is buttons,text field or some other object.I also need some assistance regarding changing number of blocks depending on word length.Also how to display the selected character on label.I do acknowledge we can take label and arrange characters on it,but what is the recommended way,should I take a label for each character or a single label,then allow spacing depending on character selection.If so how should I do this.

People would have wondered what I have tried,but please help me as I am new to these kind of puzzle games,at least provide me with some understandable source to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a lot more precise and logical answer to my problem,

As alpha mentioned,we need to shuffle the array and form a sorted one,we need to assign a random word to jumbledWord based on index,say for instance:

```
int randomWordIndex = (int)arc4random%[greWordsArray count];
self.jumbledWord = [greWordsArray objectAtIndex:randomWordIndex];
```

Now we are ready with creating buttons based on word length.Here it is:

```
-(void)buttonsCreation:(int)noOfButtons
{
    NSMutableArray *charactersArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.wordButtons = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:20];

    BOOL record = NO;
    int randomNumber;

    for (int i=0; [charactersArray count] < jumbledWord.length; i++) //Loop for generate different random values
    {
        randomNumber = arc4random() % jumbledWord.length;//generating random number
        if(i==0)
        {
            [charactersArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:randomNumber]];
        }
        else
        {
            for (int j=0; j<= [charactersArray count]-1; j++)
            {
                if (randomNumber ==[[charactersArray objectAtIndex:j] intValue])
                    record = YES;
            }
            if (record == YES)
                record = NO;
            else
                [charactersArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:randomNumber]];
        }
    }

    int arrayValue;
    float x = 100.0;
    float y = 100.0;
    for(int i=0;i<[jumbledWord length];i++)
    {
        if(i>=0 && i<10)
        {
            arrayValue = [[charactersArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
            x = x + 33;
            UIButton *characterButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            characterButton.frame = CGRectMake(x,175.0, 35.0, 35.0);
            [wordButtons addObject:characterButton];
            NSString *characterValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[jumbledWord characterAtIndex:arrayValue]];
            [characterButton setTitle:characterValue forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [characterButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [characterButton setTag:arrayValue];
            [self.view addSubview:characterButton];
        }
        else if(i>=10 && i<15)
        {
            y = y + 33;
            UIButton *characterButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            characterButton.frame = CGRectMake(y,200.0, 35.0, 35.0);
            [wordButtons addObject:characterButton];
            NSString *characterValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[jumbledWord characterAtIndex:i]];
            [characterButton setTitle:characterValue forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [characterButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [characterButton setTag:i];
            [self.view addSubview:characterButton];
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that the x and y values may vary based on one's requirement.I have briefly set co-ordinate locations of x and y based on word length,You may change if you want,thanks :)

Hope it helps some one,happy coding!!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have wordsArray which consists of 3k words

```
int randomWordIndex = arc4random%[wordsArray count];

NSString *jumbledWord = [wordsArray objectAtIndex:randomWordIndex];
NSMutableArray *characterArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
// character array having all characters of array

for (int i = 0; i< = [jumbledWord length]); i++)

{

   int randomCharacterIndex = arc4random%[jumbledWord length];
   [characterArray insertObject:
                        [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",
                          [jumbledWord  characterAtIndex:i]] 
                  atIndex:randomCharacterIndex] ;

}
```

Now you can show it using label or tableview or anything

Comment: How about displaying the shuffled words in blocks,should I use buttons or text fields or other object,how about displaying the pressed character in label,should I use multiple labels or only 1 label,and what about displaying letters when ever new button is pressed

Comment: @EshwarChaitanya you can use table view.... because table view having this method....

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath 
       toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath

Comment: No no no,I guess you misunderstood the context,actually there is no scope for table view in my game,I want the jumbled word in blocks on view that appears for user to play,upon selection the characters should appear above the jumbled blocks,be it be on label or what ever it is.

Comment: ok... now you can use buttons or labels depends on u.... and ur requirements... ENJOY!! :)

Comment: But I am facing error at line arc4random%[wordsArray count],it says "invalid operands to binary expression"

Comment: Thanks,it helped,but it is now crashing at character array insertObject statement,i.e. complier is throwing -[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds exception!!

Comment: Just change this..... because we are inserting at location which is not available... [characterArray insertObject:
                        [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",
                          [jumbledWord  characterAtIndex:randomCharacterIndex]] 
                  atIndex:i] ;

Comment: I was forced to change the %@ to %hu format,I mean it threw a warning along with a suggestion to replace %@ with %hu and can I know the reason why,more over when I logged character array,I could see 108 7 times and when I quit the application and again ran,it showed 109 7 times,don't understand what's happening out there :x

Comment: typedef unsigned short unichar;
actually unichar is unsigned short that's why you have to use %hu... just try to print character array size everytime.... and see what comes

Comment: NSLog(@"character array is %d",[characterArray count]); ,yeah I am getting the words size in the array,say 7 once,9 next,again 7 and so on.Now how should I pick the character from word and display in button or what ever object it is

Comment: Now just take no. of labels equal to size of characterArray... or everytime make a loop of first digit in character array to last array and then add same text in label

Comment: I found the answer,thanks for helping me in getting started,I have up-voted :)